# Setting Flags in Android Chrome

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android

I have an Android 4.2 device with the latest Chrome-Browser.
in this Browser I can set some custom flags, by browsing the URL `about:flags`
If I screw it up, I can go to the app-settings, delete the Chrome-Data and everything is set to default. So far so good.

My question is:
Where exactly are those custom flags saved? I guess somewhere in the `/data/data/com.android.chrome` directory. But unfortunately I am not able to find it. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953311/4720957) by Satyam Koyani tells us that the file that keep those flags is named Local State, though the answer isn't Android specific.

It turned out to be true. The location of the file is `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Local State`. It's a JSON file but the extension is missing so your text editor may run into issues with formatting when you open it. For those who can pull the file into PC, you may try Firefox addon [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/). Make sure to rename the file to add `.json` as an extension before opening it.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; hover to know details)</sub>

[image: IMG: Chrome Flags]
[image: IMG: 'Local State' file]